# Choosing which rma to use for meta-analysis of proportions

Tags: r

I have 2 studies that report the trajectories/proportions of individuals who experience pain over time (e.g. at 1-month 30% experience pain and 70% don't, at 2-months each of these branches form 2 more branches of pain/pain-free etc).

I want to meta the proportions reported in these 2 studies (I know), and I have a question. say I make my dataframe for the first timepoint:

```
study = c("1", "2")
ni = c(539, 89)
xi = c(121, 31)
xii = c(418, 58)
onemonth <-data.frame(study, xi, xii, ni)
```

Then I want to model and logit transform my data.. I am unsure if I should use a random effects model to try and account for differences between the studies

```
res <- rma(measure = "PLO", xi = xi, ni = ni, data = onemonth)
```

OR if I should be using the random-effects logistic regression model because my outcome is dichotomous. I have seen both reported.

```
res <- rma.glmm(measure = "PLO", xi = xi, ni = ni, data = onemonth)
```

I would then transform my data back:

```
predict(res, transf = transf.ilogit, digits = 2)
```

Any/all help and thoughts would be very appreciated!